# iOS: Simplest way to place results of NSFetch into array

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I want to create an array of users.  What is the simplest way to get the results of a fetch and place them into an array?

Here is my current code that uses NSFetchedResultsController.  Thanks for helping to clear my brain fog...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
NSArray *users = fetchedResultsController;// not working. What should this be?
}

-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController==nil){
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest= [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [chModel sharedInstance].managedObjectContext;
               NSEntityDescription *entity =[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        fetchRequest.entity=entity;

        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor,nil];
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors=sortDescriptors;

        self.fetchedResultsController=[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
        self.fetchedResultsController.delegate=self;
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@,%@",error,[error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }

    }
    _users = [_fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchedResultsController` is the `NSFetchedResultsController` instance  not any of its contents.

Since you have to instantiate the results controller to get the fetched objects, move the line

```
_users = [_fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
```

into `viewDidLoad` like

```
_users = [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
```

Comment: I think you are right so have marked correct.  However, placing a log statement in fetched results controller, I see it is not getting called.  Other than _users = [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]; is there anything else I have to do to make sure it gets called?  It follows nsferchedresultsdelegate protocol

Comment: According to the code it's supposed to be called each time the getter is called.